# How to set the default choice for Symfony Form Builder EntityType Field

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have an EntityType Field in my Symfony Form Builder. The buildForm method looks like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('title', TextType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Title',
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => "form-control",
            ),
        ))
        ->add('language', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => Language::class,
            'label' => 'Language',
            'multiple' => false,
            'expanded' => false,
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $entityRepository)
            {
                return $entityRepository
                    ->createQueryBuilder('l')
                    ->where('l.inUse = true')
                    ->andWhere('l.id > 0');
            },
        ));
}
```

As you can see, this creates a multiple selection field with all languages from my database available to pick from. However, I want to modify this so the specific language (for example ID = 12) will be always selected while creating new title. Can anyone tell me how to achieve this?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29031948/4782314) might help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39752649/setting-a-default-choice-on-symfonys-entitytype answers to this question might help