# EntityType Symfony set default as null

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I would like how could a make that my first option of an EntityType is NULL.

I've tried with a placeholder, but is not possible because when I try to register the form it obligate to select a different option which is not the place holder.

I'm trying something like this:

```
->add('idacademicprogram', EntityType::class, array(
            "class" => 'AppBundle:Academicprogram',
            'placeholder' => 'Choose an option',
            "attr"=>array(
                "class" => "form-iduser form-control",
                "required" => false
            )))
```

Comment: Why you do not want to set in in entity?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok i fixed changing required on global array, not on attr.

Would be something like this:

```
->add('idacademicprogram', EntityType::class, array(
            "class" => 'AppBundle:Academicprogram',
            'placeholder' => 'Choose an option',
            'required' => false,
            "attr"=>array(
                "class" => "form-iduser form-control"
            )))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fix by adding data or empty_data

data will contain the value of list for example (a=>1, b=>22, c=33)
then the code will be:

```
->add('idacademicprogram', EntityType::class, array(
        "class" => 'AppBundle:Academicprogram',
        'placeholder' => 'Choose an option',
        'required' => false,
        'data' => <Value>,
        "attr"=>array(
            "class" => "form-iduser form-control"
        )))
```

and empty_data it will contain null value
code will be like this:

```
->add('idacademicprogram', EntityType::class, array(
        "class" => 'AppBundle:Academicprogram',
        'placeholder' => 'Choose an option',
        'required' => false,
        'empty_data' => '',
        "attr"=>array(
            "class" => "form-iduser form-control"
        )))
```